Flows - empty the field
I'm finishing a flow, but I'm missing an additional functionality that considers the following:

if a user unsubscribes and is then removed as a member of the accounts team,
I need the field to be empty after deleting the user.

In other words, I need to clear the field, as it should be able to be occupied by another user later.
Do you understand? If someone knows how I can do this, such as by creating a variable that I can insert into an update element, I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance, regards!

You need to provide more information about your flow (screenshots - use [edit]) and what you've tried. As it stands, you are asking the Community to do your work for you

If you want people to make an effort to craft a helpful response, I think you need a bit more effort clarifying your question. You didn't even specify what field on what object you're trying to clear.

Have you considered simply assigning no value to the field? This sets it to null.

As Phil W mentioned in the comments, you can use an Assignment element and leave the value field blank for the field.


thank you infinitely!
